# Sending video stream from NodeJS to python in real time

Tags: python, node.js, ffmpeg, webrtc, mkfifo

I'm using a NodeJS server to catch a video stream through a WebRTC PeerConnection and I need to send it to a python script.

I use NodeJS mainly because it's easy to use WebRTC in it and the package 'wrtc' supports RTCVideoSink and python's aiortc doesn't.

I was thinking of using a named pipe with ffmpeg to stream the video stream but 3 questions arose :

- Should I use python instead of NodeJS and completely avoid the stream through a named pipe part ? (This means there is a way to extract individual frames from a MediaStreamTrack in python)
- If I stick with the "NodeJS - Python" approach, how do I send the stream from one script to the other ? Named pipe ? Unix domain sockets ? And with FFMpeg ?
- Finally, for performance purpose I think that sending a stream and not each individual frames is better and simpler but is this true ?

Thanks all !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found that the MediaStreamTrack API of Python's `aiortc` has `recv()`.

It's a Coroutine that returns the next frame. So I will just port my NodeJS script to python using this coroutine to replace `RTCVideoSink`. No piping or whatsoever !

Comment: Hi Tristan Delort, i am new in webrtc, then i need to send stream from nodejs to python. Can you tell me more about your solution?

Comment: @btlam87 What I did in the end is just use NodeJS to make a signaling server. A web browser client would then connect to the signaling server and the signaling server would setup a connection between my python process and my web browser. I then just use aiortc which is a WebRTC binding for python and handled the webrtc stream there.